# How do you customize an XML layout of a navigation drawer selection?

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-studio, navigation

Does anyone know how to do this?!?

I have looked everywhere online for 3 days now and every single tutorial only shows you how to make the drawer, but the problem is actually PUTTING THINGS AS THE LAYOUT for each selected item.

Please Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the exact answer you are looking for but I built a Navigation Drawer with the AppCompat (ActionBarActivity) library.  I have also added things like spinners (drop down lists) into the Nav Drawer XML for a different screen.

Note: In this example I actually add entries programmatically into the XML but the XML is the framework for the drawer. I essentially make a vertical linear layout, scrollable list of links under id `externalLinks`.

Disclaimer: The purist Material Design person will note that my navigation drawer is below the action bar but I like the little hamburger -> arrow icon that is provided and didn't want to cover it up. The difference is the layout_MarginTop of actionBarSize.

Hope this helps!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:background="@color/background"
    >

<!-- The main content view -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <include layout="@layout/common_toolbar"/>
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/login_scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
<!-- There is a bunch of layout that I removed because it is just my app's screen and isn't part of the answer -->
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        />
    <ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/background"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/navMoreTitle" 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/navExternal"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingStart="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                android:minHeight="30dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:background="@color/white"
                />
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/externalLinks" 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@color/background"
                >
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```